# Количество делителей числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел, факторизация

Как найти количество делителей числа.

Например число

```
20 -> 1 2 4 5 10 20

1 -> 1 = 1

2 -> 1, 2 = 2

4 -> 1, 2, 4 = 3

5 -> 1, 2 = 2

10 -> 1, 2, 5, 10 = 4

20 -> 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 10 = 6

1 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 4 + 6 = 18
```

Comment: Перебором не пробовали?

Comment: Чем не подходит обычный перебор? Запускаем цикл, в котором ставим условие `if(n℅i==0) cout << i;` где n - ваше число. Вывод можно организовать в какой нибудь вектор.

Comment: в цыкле проверяете или число поделилось без остатка, если да то делитель заносите в массив и в конце проверяете длину массива. Таким образом длина массива будет количеством делителей, а в массиве будут все делители.

Comment: Какое у вас ограничение по входным данным?

Comment: Почему у пятерки делитель 2? Почему 20 имеет два делителя 10? Ошибка или глубокий смысл?

Comment: @Nik Вообще достаточно цикла до корня квадратного из числа. только в массив писать сразу и делитель и частное.

Answer (score 5):

Откровенно говоря, ничего умнее, чем перебор простых делителей числа до `sqrt(N)` не вижу. Ну, а потом - перебор сочетаний этих простых делителей в составные делители. Понятно, что при нахождении простого делителя делим число на него и начинаем все сначала. И не менее понятно, что количество всех сочетаний (== количество делителей) есть просто произведение всех степеней простых делителей, увеличенные на 1. Ну, например, `360 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1`, так что число делителей `(3+1)*(2+1)*(1+1)=24`.

Если числа небольшие - можно просто перебор всех подряд делителей до `sqrt(N)`, с учетом, что для каждого такого делителя, отличного от 1, есть соответствующий делитель с обратной стороны от `sqrt(N)`.

Код нужен? :)

Update: пример - [вывод количества всех делителей (включая 1 и само число)](http://ideone.com/ZgcMoz)

Comment: Ну если совсем все плохо, то можно массив простых чисел в константы записать, чтобы не все до корня проверять. А можно в сторону вероятностных тестов попробовать посмотреть http://e-maxx.ru/algo/factorization

Comment: @pavel Так вы получите только разложение на более мелкие числа. И к каждому все равно надо делать свой вариант...

Comment: Если это сделать быстро, то дальше ещё быстрее будет. Если числа ну очень большие а делителей немного то эффект будет.

Comment: @pavel А потом их компоновать... По-моему, на простые делители - лучше всего, после этого количество делителей - просто произведение увеличенных на 1 степеней (минус 1, если не считать само число). Простые числа теоретически линейным решетом Эратосфена дают `O(sqrt(N))`, но вот дальше что-то у меня оценка не получается. Но никак не хуже `O(sqrt(N)*lg N)`, нет? тогда выходит `O(N*lg N)` - что-то в таком духе?

Comment: Да, на простые конечно удобнее всего, просто если числа большие (например в криптографии полезли) то до корня это слишком долго, поэтому есть специфические методы которые порядка log^2 работают.  В предыдущем комментарии я имел ввиду что хоть как-то разделить число уже полезно, т.к. мы переходим к той же задаче но с меньшим размером. Конечная цель - факторизация.

Comment: @pavel А, теперь понял вашу мысль, да, конечно. Но если ограничиваться обычными 32-битными типами, то перебор вполне пойдет...

Comment: Кстати у вас чуть ошибка, для 1 как раз есть обратный элемет- само число, а вот для точного корня обратного нет.

Comment: @pavel Ну, в исходном вопросе мне показалось, что само число как делитель не рассматривается. Ну а корень - понятно, что обратный такой же, так что... :) Вобщем, код я набросал, если где ошибка - допускаю, что может быть, писал на бегу, что называется, проверял только на 3-5 числах...

Comment: Найдя один делитель, можно разделить на него, и искать дальше от текущего делителя до корня из нового, меньшего числа.

Comment: @VladD Мда... а ведь и в самом деле, кому-то это может показаться не очевидным. Понятно, что в коде я именно так и поступал. Но при переборе ВСЕХ делителей (включая составные) это как раз делать не нужно.

Comment: Вообще для этой задачи лучше бы подошла модифиция решета, в которой вместо флага простоты хранится один из делителей числа(обычно наименьший,  можно наибольший). Сложность построения та же

Comment: @Harry: Ну, быстрее будет перебрать все _простые_ делители. Если разложение на простые множители имеет вид `p1^k1 * ... * pn^kn`, то количество _всех_ делителей, очевидно, равно `(k1 + 1) * ... * (kn + 1)`.

Comment: @VladD Что-то из меня хреновый писатель сегодня. Я пишу, казалось бы, то же самое, но получается не так :) В коде я именно так и поступаю.

Comment: @Harry: И правда, что-то я разучился читать текст :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно, найти алгоритм и немного получше, чем перебор простых делителей числа до `sqrt(N)`.

Обратим внимание на тот факт, что любое число, можно представить как произведение простых множителей, таким образом если мы нашли один простой делитель, то далее нам не надо искать делители `N`, а надо искать делители от частного `N/x`, где `х` - наш простой делитель.

Например так. (Извиняюсь за C#)

```
uint[] simpl_arr = //массив заполненный простыми числами

public List<int> GetSimpleDividors(uint number)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    uint s = Convert.ToUInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number)));

    for ( int i = 0 ; simple_arr[i] < s ; i++ ) 
    {
        if (number % simple_arr[i] == 0)
        {
            result.Add(simple_arr[i]);
            uint quotient = number / simple_arr[i]; 

            var tmp = GetSimpleDividors(quotent);

            if (tmp.Count > 0)
            {
                 result.AddRange(tmp);
            }
            else
            {
                 result.Add(quotent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: А можно код с рекурсией? Я честно не представляю _как_ она делает код лучше.

Comment: @pavel, я плюсы почти не помню... :), но здесь напрашивается явно - находим первый делитель, и вызываем ее же для частного.

Comment: лёгким движением руки сложность из очевидного корня становится что-то порядка n^(5/6)

Comment: @pavel `n^(5/6)` это и есть корень

Answer (score 0):

Можно в цикле через алгоритм Евклида считать до деления на 0.
До конца цикла проверять результат деления: если остаток от деления равен 0, то прибавить 1 к счётчику.
В счётчике считаем количество делителей.