# Требуется найти количество делителей n-значного числа (n > 20)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Написал программу, но выдает неправильные ответы. Когда вводишь длинное число, почти всегда дает 2, хотя делителей много и много больше. Вопрос, что не так?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    long long int n; 
    int amount = 0;
    cout << "Введите n-значное число, у которого вы хотите найти количество делителей: ";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> n;                   //исходное число

    if (n % 2 == 0)                          /* если число четное, то делим его на два и к количеству делителей прибавляем 2
                                                     (само число является делителем и плюс то, на что мы разделили, итого +2)*/        
{
    n /= 2;                                  
    amount += 2;                          
    for (long long int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)amount++;
    }
}
else
{
    for (long long int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)amount++;
    }
}

cout << "Количество делителей введенного вами числа = " << amount << endl;
system("pause");
```

Comment: В отладчике посмотрите что ваша программа делает на самом деле.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Количество делителей числа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562346/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @Harry в возможном дубликате рассматривается случай чисел > `10^20`?

Comment: В данном вопросе рассматривается тип `long long int`, а на этот вопрос там вполне отвечено. Я высказал свое мнение; для закрытия с ним должно согласиться еще 4 человека - так что если я неправ, ничего страшного не случится, не так ли?

Comment: @Harry страшного не случится, но лучше добавляйте ник в ответ, а то уведомления не приходят :)

Comment: @alexolut Sorry, сам другим напоминаю, так что сапожник без сапог :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы выполните эту простую программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::digits10 << std::endl;
}
```

то увидите, что на консоль будет выдано следующее значение

```
18
```

Это означает, что невозможно поместить 20 десятичных знаков в объект типа `long long int`. Так что скорей всего вам надо переписывать программу, чтобы вводить число как строку.

Что касается вашего алгоритма, то, так как вы подсчитываете любые делители, а не только простые делители, то данное предложение

n /= 2;

может привести к потери одного делителя, как, например, 4 для числа 12.

Мне представляется, что более разумно было бы искать число простых делителей числа, а не всех, какие имеются.

Также обратите внимание, что для циклов можно сократить условие

```
for (long long int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
{
    if (n % i == 0)amount++;
}
```

Comment: а если мы будем вводить как строку, то как тогда работать с ней, как с числом? Ведь тогда все равно придется перевести ее в инт, и знаков памяти все равно не хватит

Comment: @RomaMikov Можно разбить на две части число, а затем сравнивать остатки от деления. Например, Число 12 можно представить в виде 2 чисел 6 и 6. При делении на 4 каждое из них даст в остатке 2. Сумма остатков равна 4, следовательно исходное число делится нацело на 4. Либо вам придется писать свой класс.:)

Comment: тогда возникает другая проблема. Допустим, у нас есть число 1000 и на него не хватило памяти, ввели в виде строки. Как теперь ее компьютер представит в виде 500 и 500, если это строка и делить (как число, не делить на части, а делить математически) нельзя?

Comment: @RomaMikov Да просто делите строку пополам, каждую половину приводите к целому числу, а затем можете выровнять числа, чтобы они были равными, если число четное, или чтобы одно было на 1 больше другого. Как-то так.:)

Answer (score 1):

Если работать с `long long`, то перебор простых делителей числа до `sqrt(N)` в принципе решает проблему. Ну, а потом - перебор сочетаний этих простых делителей в составные делители. Понятно, что при нахождении простого делителя делим число на него и начинаем все сначала. И не менее понятно, что количество всех сочетаний (== количество делителей) есть просто произведение всех степеней простых делителей, увеличенные на 1. Ну, например, `360 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1`, так что число делителей `(3+1)*(2+1)*(1+1)=24`.

Если числа небольшие - можно просто перебор всех подряд делителей до `sqrt(N)`, с учетом, что для каждого такого делителя, отличного от 1, есть соответствующий делитель с обратной стороны от `sqrt(N)`.

Вот пример для `int` - [вывод количества всех делителей (включая 1 и само число)](http://ideone.com/ZgcMoz)

Если нужно число побольше - нужно использовать длинную арифметику.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам это поможет, то вот решение чуть-чуть побыстрее будет:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 2 , count = 0;
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    while(i <= sqrt(a))
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
            count++;
        i++;
    }
    if(sqrt(a) == (int)sqrt(a))
        cout<<count+2 + (count-1);
    else
        cout<<count+2 + (count);
}
```

здесь `a` - это переменная и дальше идет вывод количества делителей