# Количество чисел n, у которых число делителей равно числу делителей n+1

Tags: c#, алгоритм, теория-чисел

Сама задача на первый взгляд кажется довольно простой:

> Найти количество таких чисел n (n<10^5), у которых число делителей равно числу делителей числа n+1

Вот мое решение:

```
static int NumberOfDividers(int number)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
                if (number % i == 0)
                    counter++;
            return counter;

        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                if (NumberOfDividers(i) == NumberOfDividers(i + 1))
                    counter++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }
```

Но алгоритм работает очень долго, какие есть варианты для его упрощения?

Comment: Количество чисел `n` таких что `n` и `n+1` имеют одинаковое число делителей является бесконечным ([Roger Heath-Brown (1984)](https://oeis.org/A005237)). Если известно разложение числа на простые множители `Product p^e(p)`, то количество делителей числа равно [`Product (e(p) + 1)`](https://oeis.org/A000005). Вот для тестирования, пример на Питоне, который генерирует натуральные числа и их простые множители, чтобы найти число делителей для каждого числа и вывести кол-во чисел для которых [`tau(n) == tau(n+1)`](https://ideone.com/DoIXZB).

Comment: к примеру, результат для `n<10^6` равен [102093](https://ideone.com/Tfhnab).

Comment: Это очень и очень смешная задача!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала уберем лишние вычисления из основного цикла. Обратите внимание, что на каждой итерации вы вычисляете количество делителей для обоих чисел, хотя на каждой предыдущей итерации для меньшего числа значение уже было вычислено.

```
void Main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        int next = NumberOfDividers(i);
        if (current == next)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        current = next;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(counter);//10585 
}
```

Только это изменение уменьшит время работы вдвое.

Теперь разберемся с вычислением количества делителей.

Любое число делится на 1 и себя, поэтому сразу запишем 2 в счетчик, или 0, если это единица.

```
static int NumberOfDividers(int number)
{
    int counter = number == 1 ? 0 : 2;
```

Также как и с простыми числами, нет смысла перебирать все предшествующие значения, достаточно перебрать значения до корня из заданного числа. Если есть делители меньше корня, то им будут соответствовать парные делители больше корня.

```
    double root = Math.Sqrt(number);
```

Если число является квадратом, то один из делителей будет равен корню, проверяем и добавляем единицу в счетчик остальные делители парные. Для проверки нужна только целая часть корня, иначе при сравнении мы никогда не получим равенства ([см. этот вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/198316)). Кроме того, если исходное число - единица, эта проверка добавит в счетчик ее единственный делитель и функция вернет 1, как и должна.

```
    int intRoot = (int)root;
    if(intRoot * intRoot  == number)
        counter++;
```

Остался основной цикл. Начинаем с 2, т.к. единица и само число уже учтены. Делители ходят парами, поэтому счетчик увеличиваем на 2. Исключением является корень из числа, но его мы уже учли.

```
    for (int i = 2; i < root; i++)
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            counter +=2;//делители ходят парами. поэтому увеличиваем сразу на два.
        }
    return counter;
}
```

После всех манипуляций суммарное время выполнения, по грубым замерам*, уменьшилось с ~3 минут до ~0,4 секунды. Т.е. примерно в 450(!) раз.

---

*стандартный тестовый стенд не собирал, данные со встроенного счетчика времени LiNQPad

Answer (score 3):

Я прошу прощения, но на C# пас. Зато могу набросать на C++ :)

Итак, чтобы посчитать количество делителей - раскладываем число на простые сомножители; количество делителей после этого определяется как... как [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562346/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/562360#562360) :) - там расписано.

Искать делители просто - достаточно проверять простые числа до квадратного корня из числа, причем само число всякий раз уменьшаем делением на найденный простой делитель - для скорости. Быстрый квадратный корень передираем у Уоррена в "Алгоритмических трюках"; но можно использовать и обычный `sqrt`.

Считаем для каждого числа один раз, запоминая значение для предыдущего числа.

Все, собирая все вместе -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

unsigned int primes[] = {
    2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59,
    61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127,
    131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193,
    197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269,
    271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317
};

inline unsigned long isqrt(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long x1, g0, g1;
    if (x <= 1) return x;
    int s = 1;
    x1 = x - 1;
    if (x1 > 0xFFFF)     { s = s +  8; x1 >>= 16; }
    if (x1 > 0xFF)       { s = s +  4; x1 >>=  8; }
    if (x1 > 0xF)        { s = s +  2; x1 >>=  4; }
    if (x1 > 0x3)        { s = s +  1; }

    g0 = 1ll << s;
    g1 = (g0 +(x>>s)) >> 1;
    while( g1 < g0) {
        g0 = g1;
        g1 = (g0 + (x/g0)) >> 1;
    }
    return g0;
}

int factors(unsigned long m)
{
    map<int,int> fs;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; m > 1 && primes[i] <= isqrt(m);)
    {
        if (m%primes[i]) { ++i; continue; }
        m /= primes[i];
        fs[primes[i]]++;
    }
    if (m > 1) fs[m]++;

    int count = 1;
    for(auto q: fs) count *= (q.second+1);
    return count;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int total = 0, last = 1;

    for(unsigned long n = 2; n < 100000; ++n)
    {
        int count = factors(n);
        if (last == count)
        {
            // cout << (n-1) << " vs " << n << " count = " << count << endl;
            ++total;
        }
        else last = count;
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Считает за миллисекунды - см. https://ideone.com/QRI81U

Еще раз прошу прощения за C++, а не C#...

Comment: Вот вам перевод на C# https://ideone.com/tI8ayc. Если верить таймеру идеона, то даже немного быстрее отработал чем на плюсах =) но думаю это простая погрешность. Интересное решение, мне понравилось, правда пришлось разбираться как работает std::map, чтобы правильно замену на Dictionary сделать, он не умеет добавлять элементы при обращении к отсутствующему. Ну и типы немного подрезать пришлось, иначе там жуть с приведениями начинается.

Answer (score 0):

Просто считаем число делителей чисел. Это что-то вроде решета Эратосфена. Работает очень быстро (0.027c):

```
using System;

int n = 100001;
int[] a = new int[n];

int c = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
        ++a[j];
    }
    if (a[i] == a[i - 1]) {
        ++c;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

> ```
> $ csc /nologo temp.cs
>
> $ time mono temp.exe
> 10585
>
> real  0m0.027s
> user  0m0.020s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Аналог на C++ работает 0.004с:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int n = 100001;
    int a[n] = {0};

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j += i) {
            ++a[j];
        }
        if (a[i] == a[i - 1]) {
            ++c;
        }
    }
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -O3 temp.cpp 
>
> $ time ./a.out 
> 10585
>
> real  0m0.004s
> user  0m0.000s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Comment: @Harry, что скажете?