# Количество всех натуральных делителей натурального числа n

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел, факторизация

Числовые функции
Количество всех натуральных делителей натурального числа *n* обозначается *σ<sub>0</sub>(n)*. Сумма всех натуральных делителей числа *n* обозначается *σ<sub>1</sub>(n)*.

Ввод `6` Вывод `4 12`.

Вот мой код:

```
x = int(input())
a = 0
d = 2 
s = int(x/2) + 1

for i in range(2, s): 
    if x % i == 0:
        d += 1
        a += i

print(d, x + 1 + a)
```

Пишет, что программа выполнялась долго и была прервана. Можете помочь улучшить код, чтобы он проходил по времени?

Comment: Количество - см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562360/195342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math

n = int(input())

s = 0
c = 0

for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
    if n%i == 0 and i!=math.sqrt(n):
        c+=2
        s+=(i+n/i)
    elif i == math.sqrt(n) and n%i == 0:
        c+=1
        s+=i

print(c, int(s))
```

Этот код прошёл проверку на Сириусе, пользуйся ;)

Comment: Этот код можно упростить.

Answer (score 1):

Если n - делитель числа x, то и x/n тоже делитель числа x.

*Пример для наглядности: 2 - делитель числа 18. Поэтому и 9 (=18/2) - тоже делитель числа 18.*

Таким образом, найдя один делитель, мы находим сразу два. Диапазон поиска сокращается с x/2, до sqrt(x) (для наглядности: в случае x=10000 это означает сокращение в 50 раз).

Так что примерно так:

```
s = int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1

for i in range(2, s):
    if x % i == 0:
        d += 2
        a = a + i + x/i
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а что это за x  такой? Чему он равен?
Так же программа ругается на math. Нужно подключить import math?

Comment: Тот же самый х, что и в вашем коде. Да, надо произвести import math.

Comment: Выводить нужно d и a, так? Только опять же "ругается" на a и d.

Comment: Замените моим кодом соответствующий фрагмент в вашем коде.

Comment: Простите, что так мучаю вас...
import math
x = int(input())
a = 0
d = 2
s = int(math.sqrt(x/2)) + 1
for i in range(2, s):
    if x % i == 0:
        d =d+ 2
        a = a + i + x/i
print(d, x + 1 + a)

Выводит 2 и 7.
Получается d не считается и с а что-то..

Comment: Исправил. Нужно брать корень от х, а у меня было от х/2, не поправил после копирования.

Comment: Пишет, что ответ не правильный(скорее всего у 10000). Мне кажется, что это из-за а. Может не надо в конце к а прибавлять x?

Comment: Мне открылась подсказка у этого задания
У каждого делителя d числа n, который меньше √n есть парный ему, равный n/d, больший √n. Будем учитывать их парами. Еще нужно не забыть, что если √n является делителем, то у него нет пары.

Comment: Надел в конце проверить - если число точный квадрат, то их а вычесть единицу.

Comment: можете помочь кодом?

Answer (score 0):

[Функция делителей *σ<sub>x</sub>(n)*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) вычисляется по разложению на простые:

```
import math


def factors(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        e = 0
        while n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
            e += 1
        yield 2, e

    i = 3

    n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
    while i <= n_sqrt:
        if n % i == 0:
            e = 0
            while n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                e += 1
            yield i, e
            n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
        i += 2

    if n > 1:
        yield n, 1


def sigma(n):
    c = 1
    s = 1
    for p, e in factors(n):
        c *= e + 1

        t = 1
        f = 1
        for _ in range(e):
            t *= p
            f += t
        s *= f
    return c, s


print(*sigma(int(input())))
```